# Move td contents to top of cell.

Tags: html

I have HTML table

My code is:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<p>ONE</p>
<p>TWO</p>
<p>THREE</p>
<p>FOUR</p>
</td>
<td><p>ONE</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have two tds, in the first td there are four numbers, in the second td there is only one number.

The problem is:

The number ONE in the *second* td is displayed in center, but I want to display it at the top of the td.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/ftYwC/

I want to make it look like this:

```
ONE  | ONE
two  |
three|
four |
```

Notice that the second column is displayed at the top of the cell, this is what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following style on the right side td:

```
style="vertical-align:top"
```